It is possible to stop a terminal session (screen command) if we find a certain word in its output?
I would like to end a terminal session if a certain word appears in it. Suppose I have three scripts that do the following:
./script1.sh:
#!/bin/bash
for a in water fish eat book human Mexico USA latin table violence sheep stop dog life; do sleep 2; echo $a;done

./script2.sh:
#!/bin/bash
screen -dmS mysession "/home/user/script1.sh"

the second script calls the first in a new terminal session. And,
./script3    (the third script calls the second)
#!/bin/bash
/home/user/script2.sh | tee /dev/tty | grep -m 1 "violence" &&
for session in $(screen -ls | grep -oP '\d+\.\w+'|cut -d. -f1); do
echo "${session}"; screen -S "${session}" -X quit;done

What I intend to do is that when the word, in this case, "violence" is in the terminal session, the mysession session is terminated and the bash prompt is returned. But my process is not working. When I type screen -r I see that the word skips and doesn't stop the terminal session.

I've never heard of such a cabability. It would have to be implemented either in the terminal driver, the terminal emulator, or screen. There's no general API that allows other processes to monitor what's going to a terminal.

Thank you, Cyrus, Barmar. I think that with a tee command it would be possible, sending to tty or a file. I'm stuck. Is there any topic that I can review to help?

You can't really pipe an interactive session to tee.

You could modify the script program to scan the output as it's recording it, and it could then exit if a bad word is seen.

Thank you, Barmar. When possible could you give me an example?

An example of how to modify a Linux application? No, that's way too involved for a SO answer.

You'll need some expertise in C programming.

Ok. I understand. But, I'm wondering if I can modify my script to scan the output and record the output.

A script can read the output of the commands it runs, but it has no access to the interactive terminal session.

would starting the session with logging '-L' then scanning the logfile be suitable ?

Thank you, Barmar; ticktalk, but I need to stop the screen session while it runs, is it possible with that argument?

(tested) trivial example -
searches for keyword $1 in session log file,
if matched then terminate session id matching $2
invoke passing keyword and sessionID
cat s3.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "args:: keyword:$1 :: session: $2 "

while true
do
    c=$( grep -c "${1}" screenlog.0 ) #
    if [ $c -ge 1 ]
    then
        echo "keyword: ${1} matched"
        sess=$(screen -list|grep "${2}" | awk '{print $1}' )
        echo "screen -S $sess -X quit"
        screen -S $sess -X quit
        exit
    fi
 
    sleep 1 #
done


Thank you for your help and your time, ticktalk. I have tested your code and it works. With some adjustments it could be useful.
